# When I run query from Visual Studio 2012 it retun 0 and in Toad it have result

Tags: oracle11g

I have an Oracle query to find quarterly sum of data. It returns values when I run it from `Toad` but when I run it from `vs2012` it return 0 for all sums.

**query:**

```
SELECT 
    'Q1' AS QTR,
    NVL (ROUND (SUM (
                CASE
                   WHEN I.ISSDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01/APR/2012')
                                      AND TO_DATE ('30/JUN/2012')
                   THEN
                      TOTALAMOUNT / 100000
                   ELSE
                      0
                END),
             2),
          0)
          AS TOTAL
FROM 
    INV I
WHERE 
    I.CANCEL = 0 AND I.FYCODE = 'F1213/0005'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NLS_DATE_FORMAT set in Visual Studio? Try executing  `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YYYY'` in Visual Studio.